# Algorithm used in Descriptor Matcher trainer in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

The code snippet below shows the basics of training a descriptor matcher used in object recognition.

```
detector = cv.FeatureDetector('ORB');
extractor = cv.DescriptorExtractor('ORB');
matcher = cv.DescriptorMatcher('BruteForce-Hamming')

for(i=1 to N)
{
   detector(i) = detector.detect(image(i));
   descriptor(i) = extractor.compute(image(i),detector(i));
   matcher.add(descriptor(i));

}
matcher.train();
```

The code is not syntactically correct, however I want to know how the `train()` function of `matcher` works here.

Comment: I think ORB uses hamming distance for matching. Check the src code here: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/features2d/src/matchers.cpp

Comment: I was hoping that they used some sort of classification algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

matcher.train(); for Bruteforce matcher has a void implementation , there is no index or a KD tree built, matching happens based on hamming distance between two keypoints identified as descriptors . If you use FLANN based matcher then the method matcher.train(); builds indexes and these indexes are used for matching the keypoints. If you want to use FLANN based matcher for your application following is the syntax for using FLANN based matching with binary descriptors(ORB,FREAK,BRISK).

```
  // paramerters for LSH index
 //LshIndexParams(int table_number, int key_size, int multi_probe_level);    
FlannBasedMatcher matcher(new flann::LshIndexParams(20,10,2));
```

It is advisable to use bruteforce matcher if the number of descriptors are less(i.e less than 100000 )in your train set because if you use FLANN based matching then most of the time will be lost in building and retrieving indexes, hence your application performance will come down